# highcharts line chart passing in x values

Tags: highcharts

Seems like it should be an easy enough thing but i cant see how i pass x values to a line chart.

Ive found examples like: https://jsfiddle.net/9r0sfehc/1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000// one day
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
    }]
});
```

So they pass in the y values and then have a point start in the plot options. That works fine. But im just wondering how i pass in x values too in the case i need something like that.

I tried

```
 data: [{1,29.9}, {2,71.5}, ...]
```

but that isnt correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts can take data in several different ways.  I think the one you're looking for is:

An array of arrays with 2 values. In this case, the values correspond to x,y. If the first value is a string, it is applied as the name of the point, and the x value is inferred.

```
data: [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 8]
]
```

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data